Stripe sdk not expanding object
I am trying to retrieve promo code from the checkout session complete event. On researching I found that event does not contain discount and I need to expand on it.
I tried curl and got the discount information and it contains the promo code. But when I use SDK I dont get the promo code information. Any idea why?
CURL result
"total_details": {
    "amount_discount": 110,
    "amount_shipping": 0,
    "amount_tax": 0,
    "breakdown": {
      "discounts": [
        {
          "amount": 110,
          "discount": {
            "id": "di_1PgRsPDLL6mQEvFDqa26571I",
            "object": "discount",
            "checkout_session": "cs_test_b1e9u48OHdZ5F6ITVhgUOSG3aUw6ker5ykTGPxA1qJAALWQfIDUDdlsCpH",
            "coupon": {
              "id": "D3muUbBu",
              "object": "coupon",
              "amount_off": null,
              "created": 1710630574,
              "currency": null,
              "duration": "once",
              "duration_in_months": null,
              "livemode": false,
              "max_redemptions": null,
              "metadata": {},
              "name": "williamette",
              "percent_off": 10.0,
              "redeem_by": null,
              "times_redeemed": 23,
              "valid": true
            },
            "customer": null,
            "end": null,
            "invoice": null,
            "invoice_item": null,
            "promotion_code": "promo_1Ov6MmDLL6mQEvFDcPVK9bfM",
            "start": 1721914717,
            "subscription": null,
            "subscription_item": null
          }
        }
      ],

curl command
curl -G https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions/cs_test_b1e9u48OHdZ5F6ITVhgUOSG3aUw6ker5yALWQfIDUDdlsCpH \\n  -u "sk_tes7ozsXaS6ZzKNZOca00oQDQ6H2p:" \\n  -d "expand[]"=total_details.breakdown

SDK result
"total_details": {
  "amount_discount": 500,
  "amount_shipping": 0,
  "amount_tax": 0,
  "breakdown": {
    "discounts": [
      {
        "amount": 500,
        "discount": {
          "amount": null,
          "discount": null
        }
      }
    ],
    "taxes": []
  }
} 

code
Stripe.apiKey = apiKey;

        SessionRetrieveParams params = SessionRetrieveParams.builder()
            .addExpand("total_details.breakdown")
            .build();

        // Additional option for creating a coupon on a connected account
        RequestOptions requestOptions =
            RequestOptions.builder().setStripeAccount(accId).build();

        try {
            Session session2 = Session.retrieve(chId, params, requestOptions);
            return session2;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

Any idea why SDK is not returning any information on discount on expand?

Can you check what stripe-java SDK version you are using? For context, there was a fix made in stripe-java SDK v24.14.0

⚠️ Fix broken reference to com.stripe.model.Discount from checkout.Session.TotalDetails.Breakdown.Discount (this represents a bugfix as this class would never have worked, but might be a breaking type change)

